# After installing Apache on AWS Server I can no longer SSH

Tags: apache, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create a simple webserver on Amazon cloud. But everytime I install apache once I disconnect I am no longer able to SSH back into the server.

```
djc@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ssh -v -i lobbymonitor2.pem ec2-user@ec2-23-20-4-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-23-20-4-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com [23.20.4.255] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 23.20.4.255 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ec2-23-20-4-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Is there a setting in Apache that I need to change that I am missing?

Comment: Are you stopping the instance in the meantime?

Comment: I have tried both restarting it and not. But I'be made sure to get the proper DNs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would debug it with the following steps:

1. Make sure sshd service is still running on your instance. Restarting that might help.
2. Maybe you had originally changed ssh config to use port 80 instead of 22 (which is what some people do to get around corporate firewalls). And Apache might be blocking it now.
3. Can you check if the security group (firewall configuration) for the AWS instance allows SSH access at port 22?

Comment: I will try 2. But I know it's not 3 because I am able to ssh in before. It's something with apache.

Answer (score 0):

I saved the AMI, and then relaunched a new instance. Seems that I am able to connect again.